# How do I fix my graphs getting compressed when being displayed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display graphs of a cosine function being wrapped around an exponential function e<sup>2π *f* *t*</sup> with different *f* values as an introduction to fourier transforms. The code was taken from: https://github.com/thatSaneKid/fourier/blob/master/Fourier%20Transform%20-%20A%20Visual%20Introduction.ipynb, but whenever I run it the graphs get compressed and unreadable.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

f = 3.0
t = np.arange(0,2,0.001) 

cos_wave = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
# cos_wave = 2*m.cos(2*np.pi*f*t) + 5*m.cos(2*np.pi*f*2*t)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,12)
plt.plot(t,cos_wave)
plt.title("Cosine Wave with 3 Hz frequency")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.xlabel('Time (in seconds)');


r_cord = []
min_freq_range = 0.0
max_freq_range = 10.0
sf_list = np.arange(min_freq_range, max_freq_range, 0.1)
for sf in sf_list:
    r_cord.append( [(cos_wave[i], t[i]*sf*2*np.pi) for i in range(len(t)) ] )

x_cord , y_cord = [], []
for l in range(len(r_cord)):
    x_cord.append( [amp*np.cos(theta) for (amp,theta) in r_cord[l]] )
    y_cord.append( [amp*np.sin(theta) for (amp,theta) in r_cord[l]] )




mean_list = []

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,110)
for l in range(len(r_cord)):
    plt.subplot(int(len(r_cord)/4)+1, 4, int(l+1))
    plt.plot(x_cord[l], y_cord[l])
    plt.plot(np.mean(x_cord[l]), np.mean(y_cord[l]), 'or' )
    plt.title("Sampling Freq = "+str(round(sf_list[l], 2))+" Hz")
    plt.show(block=True)
    # Storing the COM for plotting later
    x_mean = np.sum(x_cord[l])
    mean_list.append(x_mean)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `figSize`?

Comment: Yes :) I tried playing around with it, but its still getting compressed when its displayed.

Comment: What is the significance of the YouTube iframe in your code? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: I removed it and it seems to have nothing to do with the code functionality. Its a link to a video from 3Blue1Brown about fourier transformation, which is what the notebook is based on.

Comment: What happens if you remove `import seaborn as sns` and `sns.set()`?

Comment: It seems like the seaborn module is used to create the grid in the coordinate system. When i remove it im left with a white background behind my graphs.